# Ever had to deploy MVC yourself? Did you need visual studio installed at the deployment site?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, deployment

I see in the system requirements for MVC 1.0, that you need to have some flavor of visual studio 2008 installed at the deployment site.

Is this really necessary?

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=53289097-73ce-43bf-b6a6-35e00103cb4b&displaylang=en

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need Visual Studio installed to **develop** ASP.Net MVC sites.  To deploy them, you just need to make sure the MVC assemblies are available.  Phil Haack has [a good overview](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/11/03/bin-deploy-aspnetmvc.aspx) of what you need to know.

Comment: You don't. You can use any text editor like notepad if you want

Comment: @Paco, my comment was in the context of the question's download link, where it says you need Visual Studio to use some of the features of ASP.Net MVC.  I'm saying that those features require VS during development and not deployment.  I'm not saying that there is no way to develop ASP.Net MVC sites without Visual Studio.

Answer (score 3):

Of course Visual Studio is only for the development environment. To deploy the MVC website, you only need to include a couple DLLs.